# How to modify names of a numpy files list?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of numpy files in one folder, I try to  modify the name of each file in my folder `3_Traces_npy` from this format:

```
AES_Trace=1234_key=000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f_Plaintext=f9f19b259648feb20d842480745de16f_Ciphertext=a3140be40735f9f1865aa6b1b32b5667.npy
```

to this format:

```
dataArray1234_pti_f9f19b259648feb20d842480745de16f_cypher_a3140be40735f9f1865aa6b1b32b5667.npy
```

This is may code, where I am blocked how to create the nw name:

```
import os
path_For_Numpy_Files='C:\\Users\\user\\3_Traces_npy'
os.chdir(path_For_Numpy_Files)
list_files_Without_Sort=os.listdir(os.getcwd())
list_files_Sorted=sorted((list_files_Without_Sort),key=os.path.getmtime)
for file in list_files_Sorted:
    new_name= 
    os.rename(os.path.join(path_For_Numpy_Files, file), os.path.join(path_For_Numpy_Files, new_name))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could parse the file name string using [split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749195/how-can-i-split-and-parse-a-string-in-python):

```
def reformat_name(filename):
    key1 = filename.split('_Plaintext=')[1].split('_Ciphertext=')[0]
    key2 = filename.split('_Ciphertext=')[1].split('.npy')[0]
    title = filename.split('AES_Trace=')[1].split('_key=')[0]
    new_filename = 'dataArray' + title + '_pti_' + key1 + '_cypher_' + key2 + '.npy'
    return new_filename
```

Called in your for loop:

```
for file in list_files_Sorted:
    new_name = reformat_name(file)
    os.rename(os.path.join(path_For_Numpy_Files, file), os.path.join(path_For_Numpy_Files, new_name))
```