# Extract a substring from a string including a comma

Tags: python, string

I have a list of strings in a file. I am trying to extract a substring from each string and printing them. The strings look like the following -

```
Box1 is lifted\nInform the manufacturer
Box2 is lifted\nInform the manufacturer
Box3, Box4 is lifted\nInform the manufacturer
Box5, Box6 is lifted\nInform the manufacturer
Box7 is lifted\nInform the manufacturer
```

From each line I have to extract the string before `\n` and print them. I used the following Python regex to do that - `term = r'.*-\s([\w\s]+)\\n'`
This regex works fine for the 1st, 2nd and last line. But it doesn't work for the 3rd and 4th lines since there is a `,` in the string. How should I modify my regex expression to fit in that?

Expected results -

```
Box1 is lifted
Box2 is lifted
Box3 Box4 is lifted
Box5 Box6 is lifted
Box7 is lifted
```

Results obtained currently -

```
Box1 is lifted
Box2 is lifted
Box2 is lifted
Box2 is lifted
Box7 is lifted
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I split and parse a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749195/how-can-i-split-and-parse-a-string-in-python)

Comment: Do the strings contain newline characters, or do they contain a literal "\" followed by "n"? Your regex seems to suggest the latter, but a lot of the answers you've got are assuming the former.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a consistent format, you could just split on the newline:

```
''.join(YOURSTRING.split('\n')[0].split(','))
```

Edited because I missed the part about removing the comma.

Comment: But I also want to remove the `comma` while printing the output

Comment: Then split it again on a `,`. But avoid doing that, time to practice and learn regex.

Comment: Sorry, I honestly missed that so I updated, but as that's more complicated I would suggest going back to regex.

Answer (score 2):

regex is overkill for basic string operations like this. Use the built-in string methods, like partition and replace:

```
for line in lines:
    first, sep, last = line.partition('\n')
    newline = first.replace(',','')
    print (newline)
```

Edit. In case \n is a literal sequence in a line read from a file, use r'\n' instead of '\n'.

Comment: The OP is reading the strings from a file. By definition, a line cannot contain a newline, so your code cannot possibly work.

Answer (score 2):

The comma isn't part of either \W or \s character set.`term = r'.*-\s([\w\s,]+)\\n'`  should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Why not something as simple as `term = r"[*]*(is lifted)"`. Or don't use regex at all if not required.
EDIT: I think this might be better `term = r"(Box[0-9])?(, Box[0-9])*(is lifted)"`

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this? :

```
from io import StringIO

ok = '''Box1 is lifted\\nInform the manufacturer
Box2 is lifted\\nInform the manufacturer
Box3, Box4 is lifted\\nInform the manufacturer
Box5, Box6 is lifted\\nInform the manufacturer
Box7 is lifted\\nInform the manufacturer
'''
ok = StringIO(ok)
strings = [' '.join(x.split()).replace('\\n', '').replace(',', '') for x in ok.split('Inform the manufacturer')]
>>> for x in strings: print x
... 
... 
Box1 is lifted
Box2 is lifted
Box3 Box4 is lifted
Box5 Box6 is lifted
Box7 is lifted
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if the below works for you.

```
input="Box3, Box4 is lifted\nInform the manufacturer"
input=input.replace(",","",1)
print(input)
print(input[0:input.index("\n")])
input="Box1 is lifted\nInform the manufacturer"
print(input[0:input.index("\n")])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try regex and can capture the group:

> One line solution:

```
import re
pattern=r'\w.+(?=\\n)'

print([re.search(pattern,line).group() for line in open('file','r')])
```

output:

```
['Box1 is lifted', 'Box2 is lifted', 'Box3, Box4 is lifted', 'Box5, Box6 is lifted', 'Box7 is lifted']
```

> Detailed solution:

```
import re
pattern=r'\w.+(?=\\n)'
with open('newt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(re.search(pattern,line).group())
```

output:

```
Box1 is lifted
Box2 is lifted
Box3, Box4 is lifted
Box5, Box6 is lifted
Box7 is lifted
```