# Split the results from os.popen

Tags: python, linux

I'm using python3.6 for automatically finding some files in my computer:

```
import os
criteria = 'something'
file_names = os.popen('find dir -name "*%s*"' % criteria).read()
for file_name in file_names:
   #do something
   pass
```

The problem is that by doing .read(), all the file names including some criteria is concatenated into one string.
How can I get a list of file names as output in order to iterating in the 'for' loop?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I split and parse a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749195/how-can-i-split-and-parse-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the generic case, you are looking to split a string.
The easiest way is to use the built-in `.split()` method of Python's strings.
Example:

```
>>> ' 1  2   3  '.split()
['1', '2', '3']
```

For more details, see [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Comment: Thanks. It works with file_names = os.popen('find dir -name "*%s*"' % criteria).read().split('\n')[-1] #-1 because there is a '\n' that I don't need at the end

Answer (score 2):

Just add `split()` after `read()` function as below:

```
file_names = os.popen('find dir -name "*%s*"' % criteria).read().split()
```

The thing is `read` function returns raw string from output say as below:

```
>>> os.popen('find . -name "*%s*"' % criteria).read()
'./pymp-0kz_4tay\n./pymp-4zfymo3o\n./pymp-k79d3tvz\n./pymp-wq9g900h\n./pymp-v0jvlbzm\n./pymp-lc69tv22\n./pymp-3sqjot2q\n./pymp-fsfv6c3t\n./pymp-
```

where criteria is `pymp` in my case. So from the output its clear that I have to split the output by `\n` which is done by `split('\n')` method.

**Sample Output**

```
>>> file_names = os.popen('find . -name "*%s*"' % criteria).read().split('\n')
>>>
>>>
>>> for file in file_names: print(file)
...
./pymp-0kz_4tay
./pymp-4zfymo3o
./pymp-k79d3tvz
./pymp-wq9g900h
```