# How would I separate strings in a text file with a colon in python?

Tags: python, file, text

How would I loop through a text file and store a value. If I take a line from a text file, hello@aol.com:Password1, How would I store email as hello@aol.com , and password as Password1 ?

```
file = open("TEST.txt", "r")

for line in file:
    print(line)
```

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work ? Hint: python strings have quite a few useful methods...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I split and parse a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749195/how-can-i-split-and-parse-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is a useful way to "open files":](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282967/how-to-open-a-file-using-the-open-with-statement)

```
with open('TEST.txt', 'r') as f:
    f.readlines()
```

to split strings, you could use the `split` method:

```
'hello@aol.com:Password1'.split(':')
```

(the split method takes "what to split by" as an optional parameter)

As Bruno commented, you should take a look at [string methods](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_string.asp)