# How do I split up a user input so that it takes up two index places in an array? (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, function, split

I am looking to be able to take a user input of a few different words separated by commas, and then add them to an array so that each word they've put in takes up a different index value.
This is the function I am using for this:

```
array = ["cat","dog","house","car"]
print(array)

def append():#accepts a user input and adds it to the array
item = input("What would you like to append: ")
item = item.lower()
array.append(item)#appends the item variable delcared in the above statement
print ("The list is now: ",array)
```

Currently, this works by taking one user input, changing it to lowercase, adding it to the array and printing it out. I want to have it so the user can input: mouse, horse, mountain and the program will add those three items to the array all separately. At the moment it adds them all together - as it should. I've tried the split() command however all that seems to do is add them as one thing and just put square brackets around them.

Any help would be great. Cheers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I split and parse a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749195/how-can-i-split-and-parse-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You are thinking in the right direction, as one answer pointed out
> that you can use .split() method I will try to explain it a little
> more. You can create an item list to store the list of strings to be
> appended. Something like this

````
```python
item = input("What would you like to append: ")
item_list=item.split(", ")
```
````

> Now you can use for loop to append this list your original array.
> Something like this..

````
```python
for item in item_list:
    item=item.lower()
    array.append(item)
```
````

> Whole code for reference..

````
```python
array = ["cat","dog","house","car"]
print(array)

def append():#accepts a user input and adds it to the array
   item = input("What would you like to append: ")
   item_list=item.split(", ")
   for item in item_list:
       item = item.lower()
       array.append(item)     #appends the item variable
print ("The list is now: ",array)```
````

Comment: This has been a big help, thank you. I hadn't thought of making a new mini list and then using a for loop to add each one, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` func:

```
lst = string.split(", ")
```

It returns a list of strings.

input:

```
Apple, Facebook, Amazon
```

lst:

```
["Apple", "Facebook", "Amazon"]
```

**Update**

After you get the list, you can add them to the the main list (whatever you call it):

```
array += lst
```

Now `array` contains these:

```
["cat","dog","house","car","Apple", "Facebook", "Amazon"]
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, the `.split()` command is what I had tried using previously - however, when I added the lst to my code via `array.append(lst)` after using the `.split()` command the outputted array is: `["cat","dog","house","car",["Apple", "Facebook", "Amazon"]]`. Using the for loop mentioned in the other comment has worked with removing the brackets but looking at your expected outcome I think I might be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
lst = ["cat","dog","house","car"]

def append():
  item = input("What would you like to append: ")
  lst.extend(item.lower().split(','))
 
print(f'Before: {lst}')
append()
print(f'After: {lst}')
```

Comment: Yes cheers, it is something similar to this that I have used.